# Filtering a report by date

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to open a report built on a query based on a date based on a control on the form in which the open report event is generated.   Reviewing the code it is clear that the date on the report (Effective_date) is for some reason not being recognised.  Is it perhaps a date format issue?

```
Private Sub Comando145_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_ValueAddAndWastes01", acViewPreview, , "[Effective_date] = " & LastUpdateDate, acIcon

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this makes a difference:

```
Private Sub Comando145_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_ValueAddAndWastes01", acViewPreview, , "[Effective_date] = #" & LastUpdateDate & "#", acIcon

End Sub
```

OK, now that we know that works. One other thing:) You might consider testing the value before passing it. (To catch null values and any other oddness. In this scenario, an easy way would be to just check like this:

```
Private Sub Comando145_Click()

Dim dtVal As Date
If Not IsNull(LastUpdateDate) Then
    If IsDate(LastUpdateDate) Then
        dtVal = CDate(LastUpdateDate)
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_ValueAddAndWastes01", acViewPreview, , "[Effective_date] = #" & dtVal & "#", acIcon
    End If
End If    

End Sub
```

**Edit**
The reason is that just as a String needs to be in Quotes ("I am a string") a Date needs to be in Hash Marks (#01/01/2015#). If the field type is Date, or if you want the value to be treated as a date, then you will want ## :)

Comment: It most certainly does. Thank you very much.. Any words of wisdom as to why this issue requires this solution?